# Ввод двумерного массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

мне нужно вводить данные с поля textarea в двумерный массив. Вот моя форма:

```
<form name="myform2" action="script2.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="numbers" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    <textarea name="nums2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="done">Send information</button>
</form>
```

А вот собственно бред, который у меня получился:

```
<?
$myar=$_POST["numbers"];
$maay = $_POST["nums2"];


echo "<br>";
$darr = array($myar,$maay);
print_r($darr)
?>
```

Проблема в том, что после ввода данных они записываются в обычный массив, я уже всё перепробовал, не знаю как сделать нормально :с получается вот так Array ( [0] => 1 2 3 4 [1] => 5 6 7 8 ). Я понимаю, что тут всё неправильно, буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А зачем именно двумерный массив? Так-то можно просто массив в массив вложить, по принципу: [см. демо](https://ideone.com/n99ZnZ)

Comment: я так полагаю что вам надо получить массив `[ [ 'numers' => '1234', 'numbers2' => '5678' ] ]` правильно я понял?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь поместить эти данные в 2 мерный массив, если обе колонки массива у вас должны содержать данные. https://acmp.ru/asp/article/image.asp?id=220 вот так выглядит двумерный массив. т.е одно значение = два индекса. В вашем же варианте оба индекса должны ссылаться на значения. Уточните вопрос, или используйте вариант эдуарда :/

Comment: @Arendach ну это не двумерный массив уже :D мне кажется, что автор немного запутался с массивами.

Comment: @Mrage возможно :) ну я у вопросе так точно запутался

Comment: @Mrage в PHP вот это `$arr = [ [ 'numbers' => '1234', 'numbers2' => '5678' ] ];` и есть двумерный массив :) И обращаться к его элементам нужно будет таким образом: `echo $arr[0]['numbers']; // 1234`

Comment: @Эдуард какой же он двумерный, если второй же индекс укажет на обрыв массива. по сути это просто массив в массиве :) да и в php есть нормальная реализация двумерных массивов. `$flowers = array( array("розы", 100 , 15),
                  array("тюльпаны", 60 , 25),
                  array("орхидеи", 180 , 7) 
                ); `  это уже будет являться двумерным массивом. Хотя если массив будет расширяться , то эта реализация будет обретать смысл.

Comment: @Эдуард в общем то я запутан вопросом автора, совсем не понятно, что он хочет получить :)

Comment: @Mrage структура массива и у вас, и у меня - двумерная. Вы просто больше элементов прописали в массив :) Т.е., у меня массив в массиве, а у вас - массивы в массиве. На структуру массива число его элементов не влияет.

Comment: @Эдуард это вполне понятно, просто не вполне понятно, чего хочет автор. Просто для такой задачи хватило бы и вот такого кода (например) `$array = [];

$numbers = [1,2,3,5,6,7];
$numbers1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
$array[] = $numbers;
$array[] = $numbers1;
print_r($array);` вот и гадай теперь, о чем вопрос

Comment: Не хотел вас запутать :D , попытаюсь объяснить. Я ввожу числа в форму, к примеру A1 (1,2,3,4), и они записываются в массив, получается так: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ). Во вторую форму я ввожу тоже числа, и они записываются в следующую переменную, к примеру A2 (5,6,7), получается так: Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 ) . И после этого, эти 2 переменные записываются в двумерный массив $THN=($A1,$A2); И при выводе этого массива должно быть так: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 ) ).

Comment: Вся проблема заключается в считывании данных из формы в массив, прошу прощения, если щас написал полную чушь :D .

Comment: @Vova т.е., вот [так](https://ideone.com/Hoz7py) ? А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Вопрос собственно в считывании из формы и заполнении в каждую ячейку массива.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас цифры будут всегда разделены пробелами(либо любым другим разделителем), то можно воспользоваться `explode()`

```
$firstArray = explode(' ', $_POST["numbers"]);
$secondArray = explode(' ', $_POST["nums2"]);

$result[] = $firstArray;
$result[] = $secondArray;

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```